# DataTableReader.GetValue(int) is throwing ArguementOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, sqlite, exception, datatable, outofrangeexception

In a section of my code I use a DataTable and a DataTableReader to get information from my SQLite database and add it to a list. When the program gets to the reader.GetValue line the program throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. As far as I've been able to tell there is no reason for this to be happening.

```
    DataTable dt = db.GetDataTable(Program.CONN, "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'False%'");
    using (DataTableReader dtr = dt.CreateDataReader())
    {
         while (dtr.Read())
         {
              int rt = 0;
              foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
              {
                   string line = dtr.GetValue(rt).ToString();//Arguement out of range exception being thrown here
                   idList.Add(line);
                   rt++;
              }
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating through the rows, not the columns. You should do :

```
DataTable dt = db.GetDataTable(Program.CONN, "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'False%'");
int count = dt.Columns.Count;
using (DataTableReader dtr = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        for (int rt = 0 ; rt < count ; rt ++)
        {
            string line = dtr.GetValue(rt).ToString();
            idList.Add(line);
        }
     }
}
```

Or :

```
DataTable dt = db.GetDataTable(Program.CONN, "SELECT ID FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'False%'");
using (DataTableReader dtr = dt.CreateDataReader())
{
    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            string line = dtr[col.ColumnName].ToString();
            idList.Add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really. I followed his syntax but it would be better to use a for loop

Comment: @LarsTech Are you sure that **dtr[col.ColumnName]** works with DataTableReader?

Comment: I missed the columns vs rows thing.  A'aaack, good catch.  Up vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
int fc = dataReader.FieldCount;
while (dtr.Read())
{
  for (int rt = 0 ; rt < fc ; rt ++)
  {
     if (fc > rt)
     {
         if (!(dtr.IsDBNull(rt)))
         {
            string line = dtr.GetValue(rt).ToString();
            idList.Add(line);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I edited my answer.........  I like the inclusion of    if (!(dtr.IsDBNull(rt)))
         { )               but that's me.      My edits were also because of Plue's "catch", so that answer should be given credit.  However, I leave this answer here....just in case.